# BS4 проблема с елементами

Tags: python, парсер, запрос, bs4

Проблема: паршу сайт и при парсинг и на сайте есть елемент с тем же класом и тегом, но это не товар который мне нужно спарсить, это просто кнопка сохранения фильтров поиска, когда код доходит до него выдаёт ошибку что не может найти в елементе кнопки елемента с нужным класом

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Можно ли как-то отсеять елементы с товарами от этой кнопки, чтоб скрипт не трогал эту кнопку и продолжал парсить?
Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.olx.ua/d/uk/elektronika/kompyutery-i-komplektuyuschie/nastolnye-kompyutery/?currency=UAH&page=2"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

data = soup.find_all("div", class_="css-19ucd76")
for i in data:
    name = i.find("h6", class_="css-1pvd0aj-Text eu5v0x0").text
    price = i.find("p", class_="css-1q7gvpp-Text eu5v0x0").text
    city = i.find("p", class_="css-p6wsjo-Text eu5v0x0").text
    link = "https://www.olx.ua" + i.find("a", class_="css-1bbgabe").get("href")
    print(name+"\n"+"Ціна : "+ price+"\n"+city+"\n"+ link+"\n\n")
```

Прошу подсказку в виде кода

Comment: Ну так проверяйте нашёлся ли элемент, не `None` ли там. А потом уже берите `.text`, если не `None`.

Comment: В кодинге опыта не много, прошу показать это на практике

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо проверять каждый элемент найден он или нет:

```
name_item = i.find("h6", class_="css-1pvd0aj-Text eu5v0x0")
if name_item is None:
    continue
name = name_item.text
```

И так для каждого элемента. Но это муторно, конечно. Проще игнорировать исключения, хотя это и плохая практика:

```
try:
    name = i.find("h6", class_="css-1pvd0aj-Text eu5v0x0").text
    price = ...
    ...
    print(...)
except AttributeError:
    pass
```